# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32'). Why?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, jupyter

I have gone through all the similar questions but none of them answer my query. I am using random forest classifier as follows:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.predict(X_test)
```

It's giving me this error:

`ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').`

However, when I do `X_train.describe()` I don't see any missing values. In fact, actually, I already took care of the missing values before even splitting my data.

When I do the following:

`np.where(X_train.values >= np.finfo(np.float32).max)`

I get:

`(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))`

And for these commands:

```py
np.any(np.isnan(X_train)) #true
np.all(np.isfinite(X_train)) #false
```

And after getting the above results, I also tried this:

`X_train.fillna(X_train.mean())`

but I get the same error and it doesn't fix anything.

Please tell me where I'm going wrong. Thank you!

Comment: try this one : X_train = X_train.fillna(X_train.mean())

Comment: @J.K done but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**
`X_train = X_train.fillna(X_train.mean())`

**Explanation**
`np.any(np.isnan(X_train))` evals to `True`, therefore `X_train` contains some `nan` values. 
Per pandas [fillna() docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), DataFrame.fillna() returns a copy of the DataFrame with missing values filled. You must reassign X_train to the return value of fillna(), like `X_train = X_train.fillna(X_train.mean())`

**Example**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> a = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5))
>>> a[2][2] = np.nan
>>> 
>>> a
    0   1     2   3   4
0   0   1   2.0   3   4
1   5   6   7.0   8   9
2  10  11   NaN  13  14
3  15  16  17.0  18  19
4  20  21  22.0  23  24
>>> 
>>> a.fillna(1)
    0   1     2   3   4
0   0   1   2.0   3   4
1   5   6   7.0   8   9
2  10  11   1.0  13  14
3  15  16  17.0  18  19
4  20  21  22.0  23  24
>>> 
>>> a
    0   1     2   3   4
0   0   1   2.0   3   4
1   5   6   7.0   8   9
2  10  11   NaN  13  14
3  15  16  17.0  18  19
4  20  21  22.0  23  24
>>> 
>>> a = a.fillna(1)
>>> a
    0   1     2   3   4
0   0   1   2.0   3   4
1   5   6   7.0   8   9
2  10  11   1.0  13  14
3  15  16  17.0  18  19
4  20  21  22.0  23  24
>>>
```

Comment: i tried reassigning and it still gives the same error though after reassigning ```np.any(np.isnan(X_train))``` evaluates to ```False```

Comment: take a look at [this thread](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11928/valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for-dtypefloat32)

Comment: I looked at that thread before opening this one and I'm still getting value error